# import graphviz works in jupyter notebook, but the same code does not work in Pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

import graphviz works in jupyter notebook, but the same code does not work in Pycharm. I tried to setup an anaconda environment which includes graphviz and I am using that particular python interpreter from pycharm. I am stuck with this problems for last 24 hours, please help..?
[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you use the conda env that has `graphlib` is it working in pycharm?

Comment: No. I tried multiple conda envs with graphviz same thing always.. :(

Comment: I tried different versions of Python 3.8, 3.7 same again.

Comment: just to be sure, you have set the project interpreter in pycharm to the conda env haven't you?

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: When I call the same file via Pycharm terminal like python xxx.py this error does not occur. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new project, than choose "Previously configured interpreter". Check if the Python exe within the correct enviroment is selected. So in "Users/UserName/anaconda3/envs/Python/python.exe". Than when the new project is created you can check in the terminal if the correct env is enabled by looking for the term in the brackets. (Should by "Python" for you). Than try to import graphviz in the Python Console. If this works your file has a wrong configuration. Copy it in the new project and add the correct Configuration. Tried this and it works for me. Hope I could help and good luck.